# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Thinkpad X1 C2 - ALT + CTRL + T exits to black screen with cursor

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, thinkpad, shortcuts

About every five times (but with varying increments) I use the ALT + CTRL + T shortcut to get to the terminal my computer exits to a black screen with a blinking cursor. The OS is completely freshly installed with all updates applied. No third party applications are installed. I have not changed any of the default keyboard shortcuts. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but nothing changed.

Edit: I realize the terminal is also a black screen with a blinking cursor, but this is something outside the OS.

Comment: Are you sure command for this keyboard shortcut is `gnome-terminal` in keyboard settings.

Comment: Yes, nothing is changed from the default keyboard shortcut setup.